# Display issue with text +pull-left/right content in table on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a table with bootstrap and insert some pull-left and pull-right content to a column:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zoker/sgdfgkvL/

```
<td>
    <div class="pull-left">Some content</div>
    <div class="pull-right">Some other content</div>
    <a href="#">The actual content</a>
</td>
```

Now the problem on mobile devices is, that the text "The actual content" does overflow in the field (look at the fiddle)

Can somebody tell me how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `overflow-x: hidden` on `.topic-name`

**Your solution:**
apply - `white-space: normal;` to `.topic-name`

Comment: And is there also a way to force a line-break instead of just hide the overflow?

Comment: You could use something like this -> [word-wrap: break-word;](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)